# insert into table1 from table2 with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, and I want to insert data in one of the new column (Orders) of table1 from table2. Any help please, below code is not working

```
Insert into Table1 (Orders)
  Select (orders) from table2,
  Where table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: Don't you want to `update` existing rows in Table1?

Comment: I have new column "orders" in table1. I want to fill this whole column using vales from table2.

Comment: Is table1 empty or not when you start? Do you want to insert new rows into table1 for those values from table2? Or do you want to modify existing rows in table1?

Comment: Table1 consits of 5 coulmn now, 4 of them are already filled with data. But the fifth coulmn (orders) is newly added column with Default NULL.

Comment: thanks jarlh, got solution from irakliG. Thanks irakliG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
update t1
set t1.orders=t2.orders
from  Table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE    Table1 
SET       Orders = (
  SELECT  Orders 
  FROM    Table2 
  WHERE   table1.Id = table2.Id
)
```